# Utilizar array JSON en graficas chart.js

Tags: javascript, array, chart.js

estoy graficando datos con chart.js y hay un problema, yo puedo asignarle los valores normalmente con variables que en si son un array, los array son datos que estoy obteniendo de mysql, y hasta ahí todo bien, me funciona perfecto, ahora lo que no me funciona es pasarle mi array a el data de mi grafica, y al momento de pasarselo se grafica algo muy raro, aqui les dejo lo que tengo

MI VARIABLE QUE CONTIENE EL ARRAY

```
 var valor1 = array[4].sensor_valor
```

Le paso de parametro mi variable

```
let massPopChart = new Chart(myChart, {
      type:'line', // bar, horizontalBar, pie, line, doughnut, radar, polarArea
      data:{
        labels:['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6','7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12','13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18','19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
        datasets:[{
          label:'Nivel',
          data: valor1
          ,
```

Comment: revisaste la consola? te da algun error?

Comment: Si, ya lo solucione pero me falta que mi grafica, estoy usando chart.js o tambien puedo usar apex charts me lean el array

Comment: ¿Aun falta algo?

Comment: Si, no me grafica mi array, bueno si, la verdad es algo bastante raro, me grafica los valores individuales, te pongo un ejemplo, array[12,13,14,15,16] lo que me lee: [1,2,1,3,1,4,1,5,1,6], los datos de este array los estoy obteniendo de una consulta mediante php a mysql

Comment: Los recibo en formato JSON